# Howdo I turn off “colorizing”/“pretty” glyphs for text?

Tags: settings

Consider the symbols used in astronomy for example: the symbol to mean *solar masses* is not meant to be an emoticon!  And Jupiter etc. should not be a purple tile!

Most<sup>※</sup> Android programs (Chrome is shown in the comparison) use the silly versions, so that is something in the system’s text rendering.  Firefox, shown in comparison, is one of the few that show it as intended.

[image: screenshot]

How do I turn this “feature” off, or better yet restrict it to the range of emoticon characters?

I am using a rooted Galaxy Tab Pro, which is Android 4.4.2.

※ Chrome (shown), UnicodePad colorizes *misc symbols* but not Sun (U+2609) in the char map and colorizes the sun in *some* test fields but not others, Jota+, UnicodeCharmap, Built-in Internet browser app…

Comment: I have seen that- on Marshmallow whether in Firefox or Chrome,, they are the same, as in your top screenshot. My *guess* is that you can try to disable the emoticons- not sure how though

Comment: I improved the post to note several programs I tried. It's still everything other than Firefox, but now you know which ones for sure.

Comment: @beeshyams then I think you misread the question: I wrote that Firefox shows “not be emoticons” in contrast to everything else on the machine.  You reproduced what Firefox shows; now look at any other program that can display chosen characters easily.

Comment: I guess you are right, but only thing i can see is both Chrome and Firefox show the same. I don't have a KitKat device to check with other programs. Let us hope for an answer